# msf4j spring retrieve token through rest template

Tags: msf4j, wso2-msf4j

I am trying to retrieve token from WSO2 identity server, based upon the username and password received from UI.

I am able to do it from the below curl command:

curl -v -k -X POST --basic -u zbvliQjZK2aVpWV_EE2Q6PWYDUIa:xBGfoppV1DsDGoMNHDPsF5uWLKga -d "grant_type=client_credentials" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

But I am trying to do it through rest api using spring resttemaplte. Is it possible to do it? I hope yes.

Comment: can't you have client call?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't get your point. do you mean there is some client available to call? I am trying something like that:                 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
                headers.add("basic", encodedUsername+":"+encodedPassword);

                HttpEntity<String> request1 = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

                restTemplate.postForObject("https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token", request1, String.class);

Comment: Did you check with apache http client?